# Reusing the page name class that Wordpress adds to body tag

Tags: php

When viewing my blog in the browser, the body tag (on the index page) has the following class:

```
<body class="home">
```

On other pages (for this example, a page that pulls in posts that are within the category "project"), the body tag has even more classes:

```
<body class="archive category category-project category-3">
```

Both of these are rendered using the following code, contained within the html_header part:

```
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
```

I was wondering whether there was a way in which I could isolate the page descriptive class (1st example - home, 2nd example - category-project) that this command targets and use within the page.

Thanks

Comment: Your question is pretty hard to understand. Please reword and tell us your use case.

Comment: can you explain what your goal is? what you want to do exactly?

Comment: I want to use the page name to pull in page specific includes. For example, for a page that is exclusive to the category project I want to pull in an include called intro-category-project.php, which I would point the code in the direction of using
`<?php include('parts/shared/intro-' . $CLASS_THAT_THE_BODY_USES . '.php'); ?>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Function `get_body_class()` gives you an `Array` containing all the classes that are added to the body, so you can reuse them.